# HTML Input - needs space at the end, but it's not showing

Tags: javascript, html

For

```
<myDIV id="myInput" contenteditable="true"></myDIV>
```

I want to set "abcdefg " with a space behind.

Doing this

```
var myInputDIV = document.getElementById("myInput");
myInputDIV.innerHTML = "abcdefg "; //does not work
myInputDIV.textContent = "abcdefg "; //does not work
```

How to make sure that I get the space behind? Currently, the string shown in the div is just "abcdefg", without the space.

Thanks.

Comment: `<myDIV>`? That's not valid unless you register the element within HTML5 context, and it should `<div-endfix>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert spaces/tabs in text using HTML/CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792849/how-to-insert-spaces-tabs-in-text-using-html-css)

Comment: What the hell is a `myDIV` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add space in html in on of the following ways:

- add `&nbsp;` as a space sign
- add `&#160;` as a space sign

Answer (score 1):

Types of Spaces in HTML

Creates four spaces between the text- `&emsp;`

Creates two spaces between the text - `&ensp;`

Creates a regular space between the text - `&nbsp;`

creates a narrow space ( similar to regular space but slight different) -  `&thinsp;`

spacing between sentences - `</br>`

This link might help you. Check out the link here

[**SENTENCE SPACING IN HTML AND CSS**](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/html-sentences.html)