Adding tabs restructured text (rst) files
How can I tabulate information in my rst files?
Or, how do I preserve the white space I already inserted in my text?
Such that when I render the rst file (via Sphinx) to HTML the tabular formatting is preserved.
For example:
- Mr Miller:    Hates dogs
- Mrs Johnson:  Love Cats
- Ms Janey:     Owns 2 monkeys and 3 cats

I would like the text that comes after the colons to all line up.
I can't find a "tab" character. And the white spaces in my rST file are eliminated when rendering to HTML - my output format. Also, these lines in my actual rst files are bulleted and followed by API macro code before the colon, such that the macro jumps to the correct place in the code (i.e. no text can be changed before the colon). The text after the colon is used to describe my API.
The horizontal column list directive is useless here because the text is already written left to right, and that directive splits to the second (or subsequent colummn/s) after a number of lines and not after my :. Secondly, it only recognizes bulleted lists.
I tried using a table list directive - but I don't want the text in a table. Alternatively, I could use this directive if I knew how to hide the lines and the alternate row shading for only this type of table (i.e. other tables within the project would have to retain the table formatting already defined for our particular Sphinx project.

There are several alternatives, all of them are tested with Docutils (rst2html5).
The simplest way to preserve your lineup is
a literal block::

  - Mr Miller:    Hates dogs
  - Mrs Johnson:  Love Cats

which uses monotype (to keep the spacing) and
does not parse the content for rST markup.
To get the same effect but with parsing of the content use
.. parsed-literal::

  - Mr *Miller*:    Hates dogs
  - Mrs Johnson:  Love Cats_

.. _cats: kittens.html

Note: This lines up in the output, because the inline markup characters are not printed.
Better looking but non-semantic is a simple table.
With Sphinx, you may need custom CSS to get the plain table style.
.. class:: borderless

============  ==========
Mr Miller:    Hates dogs
Mrs Johnson:  Love Cats
============  ==========

Docutils provides a special markup for lists with aligned content: a field-list
For HTML5 output, you may set the field-indent with a special class value.
You may also want to use custom CSS to get the desired styling.
.. class:: field-indent-8em

:Mr. Miller:    Hates dogs
:Mrs. Johnson:  Love Cats

A field name may contain interpreted text, if the role name follows the content:
.. class:: field-indent-8em

:`Mr. Miller`:c:func::    Hates dogs
:`Mrs. Johnson`:c:func::  Love Cats

You may also use a definition list (starting the descriptions on a new line) together with custom CSS (preferably in a custom stylesheet):
.. raw:: html

   <style>dl.pet-preferences > dd {
     margin-left: 8em}
   </style>

.. class:: field-list  pet-preferences

Mr. Miller:    
               Hates dogs
Mrs. Johnson:  
               Love Cats

Actually, the white spaces are kept in the HTML source but whitespace is normalized by the browser. The original example would become:
<ul class="simple">
<li><p>Mr Miller:    Hates dogs</p></li>
<li><p>Mrs Johnson:  Love Cats</p></li>
...
</ul>

This can be used to get the desired effect by
CSS styling:
.. raw:: html

   <style>.pre-list li {white-space: pre;
                        font-family: mono;}
   </style>

.. class:: pre-list

- Mr Miller:    Hates dogs
- Mrs Johnson:  Love Cats

Of course, the CSS is better placed in a custom style sheet.

While all your suggestions work more or less with the simple example I gave, once I need to refer to the API function which is called via
:c:func:name_of_api
.... "field-list" doesn't help because of the colons that I need to use to call the API.

"parsed-literal" is not perfect - it just doesn't line up. "literal block" (::) works beautifully, but then my auto-links to the API are lost. And you're right - all the spaces are copied to the HTML, but apparently deleted (?) by the browser. I can't figure out what's going on and why I can't fix it..

"parsed-literal" does not print the markup characters (e.g. a link_ becomes a link). This must be accounted for in the source. HTML by design (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792849/how-to-insert-spaces-tabs-in-text-using-html-css). I cannot help further without a real, minimal example.

I field-lists don't work because of colons, you may try a "definition list". I added an example to my answer.

A field name may contain interpreted text, if the role name follows the content.

Hi - thanks for the answers - re the example of "definition list" where do I find your example? Secondly, re the field name including interpreted text - I don't want to enter any chars within the current list I have - there are too many lines for this to be effective. I'm sorry I can't provide an example - because those colons are used to call macros from h files and I cannot provide the links. Not sure how to provide an example. - thanks for your help!

It is in my answer just below the two examples with a "field list" (starts with a "raw" directive with styling rules that may better move to a custom CSS file).
